# Is it ok to import variables and use them inside of a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, export, create-react-app

I'm experimenting with the Google Maps API in React, and I have this function which  creates the infowindows to bind to the markers after checking if the API data were retrieved properly:

```
createInfoWindow( marker, infoWindow ) {
    fetchData ? infoWindow.setContent( infoWindowContent ) : 
    infoWindow.setContent( infoWindowError );
    infoWindow.open( map, marker );
  }
```

Now, instead of defining the infowindows content right in the .setContent() method, like this:

```
infoWindow.setContent(
  '</div>' +
       '<h2>Title: ' + marker.title'</h2>' +
       '<p>Coords: ' + marker.position'</p>' + 
   '</div>'
 ) ...
```

I would rather define the content in another file, and then export the constants inside of the method, like so:

File: InfoWindow.js

```
export const infoContent = `<div>...</div>`;
```

And then simply:

```
import { infoContent } from "./InfoWindow.js";   

infowWindow.setContent( infoContent ) ...
```

Just to clarify, I'm wondering if it's a good practice to do this, since I'm super new to React and not as knowledgeable about ES6 as well. Thanks!

P.s.: I cannot unfortunately test if this returns any error at the moment, but a general "you shouldn't do this anyway, because..." would do :)

Comment: But is `infoContent` an actual constant, or does it depend on some variables (ie `marker`)? If so, you could export a function called `getInfoContent` that takes that argument and return a string.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! At the mmoent it's a constant which holds the HTML content, and I was wondering if it was possible to maintain a relation with other variables (`marker` being one of those). I think I got what you mean, and it would make sense. Could you please elaborate on that with a formal answer? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely encouraged to decouple the HTML content to maintain readability IMO. What I would recommend, to allow you to pass `marker` is to use a getter utility function, and export that:

```
export function getInfoContent({ title, position }) {
  return `…` // HTML content, you can use title and position from marker here
}
```

Then call the getter and pass in `marker`:

```
infoWindow.setContent(getInfoContent(marker))
```

I believe this is a lot more readable than inline HTML template literals, and decouples them making it more declarative to readers. Also side-note about your ternary expression:

```
fetchData ? infoWindow.setContent( infoWindowContent ) : 
infoWindow.setContent( infoWindowError );
```

The general idea is to not have conditional operators to execute *two different calls*, but to use the operator to choose the passed expression:

```
infoWindow.setContent(fetchData ? infoWindowContent : infoWindowError);
```

Comment: That was awesome, thanks for clarifying how to properly use the ternary as well.